# in postgres, get name & schema of relations on which materialized view depends

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I'm looking to print schema & name of relations which all the materialized views in a schema depend on:

```
select c.relname, d.classid, d.objid,
  pg_describe_object(
    d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid)
from pg_class c
  join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
  left join pg_depend d on c.oid = d.objid
where n.nspname = 'direct' and d.deptype = 'n'
```

This gives something like:

```
        relname         | relname | classid | objid |                pg_describe_object                 
------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------
 cases                  |         |    2618 | 33736 | rule _RETURN on materialized view case_categories
 benefit_investigations |         |    2618 | 33928 | rule _RETURN on materialized view bi_intervals
```

The description returned gives some hint, but it doesn't contain the schema of the relation. How do I get the actual dependency schema and name? [NB I'm using postgres 9.6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT view_cs.nspname, view_c.relname, tab_cs.nspname, tab_c.relname
FROM pg_depend view_d
JOIN pg_class view_c ON view_c.oid = view_d.refobjid AND view_c.relkind = 'm'
JOIN pg_type view_ct ON view_ct.oid = view_c.reltype
JOIN pg_namespace view_cs ON view_cs.oid = view_ct.typnamespace
JOIN pg_depend tab_d ON tab_d.objid = view_d.objid
JOIN pg_class tab_c ON tab_c.oid = tab_d.refobjid AND tab_c.relkind = 'r'
JOIN pg_type tab_ct ON tab_ct.oid = tab_c.reltype
JOIN pg_namespace tab_cs ON tab_cs.oid = tab_ct.typnamespace
WHERE view_d.deptype = 'n'
```

The trick is that you have to `JOIN pg_depend` twice - once for view-rule relation and once for rule-table relation.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
AND view_c.relname != tab_c.relname
```

to WHERE statement of the accepted answer by @Boris to avoid showing dependency of the table on itself